# Broken Ignored Tags block if text can't fit on one line

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, localization, russian-stackoverflow

It's ok with english:

[image]

But, for example, on ru StackOverflow the text doesn't fit on one line, so text isn't aligned:

[image]

If I add css `width` rules to `.s-checkbox, .s-radio` it will be ok:

```css
.s-checkbox, .s-radio {
    border-top-width: 1px !important;
    border-left-width: 1px !important;
    border-right-width: 1px !important;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
}
```

Comment: Just making sure - it's just the layout that's broken, not the actual functionality?

Comment: @AdamLear yeh, just visual bug.

Comment: @AdamLear looks like here is the problem with border width. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was fixed with new responsive design.